# Mvc Listar apenas os quartos disponíveis e nao os ocupados

Tags: sql, asp.net-mvc

Tenho o seguinte problema: Uma reserva tem associada a si um cliente e um quarto. Ao criar uma reserva, tenho que preencher alguns campos (como nome do cliente, data entrada, data saída e o quarto onde vai ficar hospedado).

A seleção do quarto é feita através de um *dropdownlist* que mostra todos os quartos criados. O problema é esse mesmo, eu não quero mostrar todos os quartos criados, mas sim, todos os quartos disponíveis, ou seja, aqueles que não têm reservas na data de criação da reserva.

A *query* que montei até agora é esta:

```
SELECT Quarto.ID_Quarto FROM Quarto
LEFT OUTER JOIN Reserva ON Quarto.ID_Quarto = Reserva.ID_Quarto
WHERE DataEntrada > GETDATE()
And DataSaida < GETDATE()
OR Reserva.ID_Quarto IS NULL
```

Comment: Não entendi isso: `Aqueles que não tem reservas na data de criação da reserva.`. Poderia explicar melhor sua pergunta?

Comment: Quando faço uma reserva... tenho um atributo quarto ... nesse atributo eu tenho um dropdownlist que me mostra todos os quartos que tenho... estando eles ocupados ou nao. O que pretendo é que se alguem agora vai reservar o quarto 1 e logo de seguida outra pessoa vai reservar outro quarto... nesse dropdownlist o quarto 1 como ja foi ocupado, ele não pode aparecer nesse dropdownlist.  So quero que esse quarto apareça novamente...  quando for dada a data de saida ( check out)

Comment: Seu campo DataSaida só é preenchido após a pessoa sair? Creio que o que necessite utilizar é o not exists!

Comment: pois a minha ideia era... se der a data de entrada o quarto fica reservado, se der a data de saida, ele ja fica livre. Acha isto correto ou tem alguma sugestão melhor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Admitindo que a data de saída será sempre **maior** que a da entrada, podes usar o seguinte:

```
SELECT DISTINCT Quarto.ID_Quarto
FROM Quarto Q1
LEFT JOIN Reserva R1 ON Q1.ID_Quarto = R1.ID_Quarto
WHERE Reserva.ID_Quarto IS NULL
   OR NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM Quarto Q2 
                  LEFT JOIN Reserva R2 ON Q2.ID_Quarto = R2.ID_Quarto
                  WHERE Q1.ID_Quarto = Q2.ID_Quarto
                    AND R2.DataEntrada <= GETDATE() 
                    AND (R2.DataSaida IS NULL OR R2.DataSaida > GETDATE())
                    -- o is null é desnecessário se a data de saída é previamente cadastrada
```

Comment: O problema é que assim nos resultados obtenho todos os quartos... eu so quero obter aqueles quartos que nao têm reservas. Eu gostava de implementar isto... o cliente ao reservar o quarto... enquanto ele não der o check out... esse quarto não pode estar disponivel para outras reservas

Comment: @Heftysilva dei uma revisada na resposta, veja se assim resolve.

Comment: Obrigado por me tentares ajudar. Isso está-me a dar um erro porque o Q2 ( refereste a tabela quarto) nao tem data de entrada nem de saida... esses atributos so os tenho na tabela de reservas

Comment: SELECT Quarto.ID_Quarto
FROM Quarto
LEFT JOIN Reserva ON Quarto.ID_Quarto = Reserva.ID_Quarto
WHERE Reserva.ID_Quarto IS NULL
  AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM Reserva Q2 
                  WHERE Quarto.ID_Quarto = Q2.ID_Quarto
                    AND Q2.DataEntrada <= GETDATE() 
                    AND (Q2.DataSaida IS NULL OR Q2.DataSaida > GETDATE()))

Comment: entendi.. alterei a consulta interna pra fazer o mesmo join da externa, vê se resolve.

Comment: fiz assim e aparece-me o quarto que nao tem reserva... mas dado que os outros ja tiveram reservas mas foi dado o check out... deveriam aparecer tambem

Comment: Trocando o `AND` por `OR` deve resolver (na linha `AND NOT EXISTS`). Mudei de novo, vê se agora foi :p

Comment: Sim, com essa solução mostra-me o ID dos quartos , mas repete ... exemplo no quarto 1 tive 3 reservas e no quarto 2 nenhuma . ele mostra-me 1, 1, 1, 2

Comment: [DISTINCT](https://www.1keydata.com/pt/sql/sql-distinct.php) resovle esse problema ;) resposta alterada

Comment: Perfeito, é isso mesmo.! se quiser fazer da seguinte forma... se introduzir uma data de entrada e de saida entre o dia de hoje e amanha , respetivamente, caso ja tenha uma reserva para esse quarto nesses dias , iria por exemplo aparecer uma mensagem a dizer que o quarto ja esta ocupado para esses dias ... é possivel?

Comment: pra esse caso tem que pensar em nível de código, não de consulta ao banco. O indicado é você marcar esta resposta como aceita (se resolvemos o problema) e criar uma nova pergunta com essa outra dúvida, saca!? ;)